# How to change properties of a grid with visual state manager XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am developing a windows universal application using C# and XAML. When my app is run on a laptop I want to change the height of my child grid in this gridview named tabIcon.

```
 <Grid Name="tabGrid" Width="700">
            <GridView  Name="SpecialtyGridView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SpecialtyCollectionViewSource}}" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="SpecialtyGridView_ItemClick">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="tabIcon"  Background="#21539E" Width="290" Height="140" Margin="5,0,5,8">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SpecialityTextBlock" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="{Binding speciality}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>

        </Grid>
```

I use a visual state trigger to do this but it does not work. Here is my trigger code for laptop.

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualState x:Name="Phone">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "HeaderGrid.Height"
                 Value = "90" />
                    <Setter Target = "Instruction.Visibility"
                 Value = "Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target = "TheatreName.FontSize"
                 Value = "14" />
                    <Setter Target = "TheatreName.HorizontalAlignment"
                 Value = "Left" />
                    <Setter Target = "TheatreName.Margin"
                 Value = "0,40" />
                    <Setter Target = "PatientNameAndIDStackPanel.Margin"
                 Value = "10,0" />


                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Tablets">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "720"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>

                    <!--<Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Red" />-->
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Laptop">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

               <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "tabIcon.Height"
             Value = "60" />

                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PCs">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "1400" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Divider.Height"
                 Value = "80" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

This code works if I use it for the grid named tabGrid but does not work for the grid named tabIcon. What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use the VisualState?

Comment: Its there cant you see it

Comment: Wow... editing code and followed by this being pertly.. Very mature -.- Nonetheless i still have no clue how you apply the Style/ControlTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason, why you need to do this just in XAML?

If not, just make two DataTemplates and change it on SizeChanged event of your page or parent grid.

XAML

```
<Page SizeChanged="MainPage_OnSizeChanged">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LaptopTemplate">
        <Grid Background="#21539E" Width="290" Height="60" Margin="5,0,5,8">
            <TextBlock x:Name="SpecialityTextBlock" 
                       FontSize="26" Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding speciality}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DesktopTemplate">
        <Grid Name="tabIcon"  Background="#21539E" Width="290" Height="40" Margin="5,0,5,8">
            <TextBlock x:Name="SpecialityTextBlock" 
                       FontSize="26" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding speciality}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView x:Name="SpecialtyGridView">
</GridView>
</Page>
```

Code-behind

```
private void MainPage_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PreviousSize != e.NewSize)
        {
            if (MainPage.ActualWidth > 1024)
            {
                SpecialtyGridView.ItemTemplate = Resources["DesktopTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                SpecialtyGridView.ItemTemplate = Resources["LaptopTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Or you can even do it in VisualStateManager:

```
<VisualStateGroup>
      <VisualState x:Name="Laptop">
           <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
           </VisualState.StateTriggers>
           <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SpecialtyGridView.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LaptopTemplate}" />
           </VisualState.Setters>
      </VisualState>
      <VisualState x:Name="Desktop">
           <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024" />
           </VisualState.StateTriggers>
           <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SpecialtyGridView.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DesktopTemplate}" />
           </VisualState.Setters>
      </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```